# Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead - on redirect tag

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, react-props

```
test('Signned in > new users are redirected', () => {
    const store = mockStore({ user: {loginAction} })
    const redirect = mount(<Provider store={store}><Router history={history}><SignIn/></Router></Provider>)

    expect(redirect.find('Redirect').at(0).props()).toHaveProperty('to', '/sign-up')
})
```

I am getting this error will anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I got it
by rewriting `expect(wrapper.find('Redirect').at(0).props()).toHaveProperty('to', '/sign-up')` as `expect(wrapper.exists('SignIn')).toBe(true)`

Happy !!! :)